# averaging rows with same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables and have made joins to return results of `[ID] : [number]` per row, this all works fine but the problem is some rows will have the same `[ID]` so sample data that might be returned is:

```
1 : 564
2 : 34
3 : 76
2 : 985
2 : 47
1 : 4
```

and so on... but what I want returned is:

```
1 : 284
2 : 355
3 : 76
```

as you can see the rows with the same `[ID]` have been averaged. My question is; is there a way to do this in SQL? How would I do it? Thanks for your time.

**Query**

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.number 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.T1_id = T1.id 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T3.T2_id = T2.id
```

Comment: add `AVG([number]) as AverageNumber, GROUP BY [ID]`. You should post your entire query so that someone can give you a working version of the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, AVG(number) FROM table GROUP BY ID
```

[Average Aggregate Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that :( I'm sure I knew I had to use this but I could work it out, I think i over-complicated it in my head. Thank you @culalis

Answer (score 1):

Using what @cularis posted and your query you added, you would use

```
SELECT T1.id, Avg(T2.number)
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.T1_id = T1.id 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T3.T2_id = T2.id
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, since you haven't posted your query:

```
select ID, avg(number)
from <your query>
group by ID;
```